# Fastest way to go through all possible prufer sequences

Tags: python

In Python, I am creating an array that contains a prufer sequence, i.e. an array of length n-2 that consists of integers between 0 and n-1. For example, (3,4,3,1,2) is a prufer sequence for n=7. I do not know n in advance. I would like to create a prufer sequence, do something with that prufer sequence, create another one, do something with the new sequence, and so on.

I was wondering what the fastest way to generate all n^(n-2) prufer sequences.

Comment: If I understand correctly, a prufer sequence would be `range(n-1)` in python, all possible sequences would be `[range(i-1) for i in range(1,n)]`

Comment: after your example I think you would just want [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) `(range(n-1), repeat=n-2)`

Comment: I think these are very good comments, and before someone answers performance / optimal algorithm questions it might be great to edit the question with the application of the suggestions from @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen so we get an idea if there is a faster way ...

Comment: That seems to work, and is fast enough for what I am doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be looking for the [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of the [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) `0<=x<n-1`, the function [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=cartesian%20product#itertools.product) will do this for you:

```
for seq in itertools.product(range(n-1), repeat=n-2):
    do_stuff(seq)
```